# Pickeling results of postgresql query via psycopg2

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, pickle, psycopg2

I'm querying the PostgreSQL database via the psycopg2 library. The response of the query this way is [cursor object file](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html). Because of the size of the query, I'm trying to avoid re-query it and instead - save the query result as a [pickle](https://pythonprogramming.net/python-pickle-module-save-objects-serialization/).

Unfortunately, when I trying to execute code for that:

```
import psycopg2
import pickle

# Connect to an existing database
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="DB", user="my_user", password="****", host="12.34.56.78")

# Open a cursor to perform database operations
cur = conn.cursor()

# Query the database and obtain data as Python objects
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM my_table[...];")

# Attempt to pickle the output
pickle_out = open("output.pickle","wb")
pickle.dump(cur, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()

# Close communication with the database
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

An error massage raised:

```
TypeError: can't pickle psycopg2.extensions.cursor objects
```

**What is a straight forward way to save the results of SQL query via python for future use?**

Note: I am not obligated to use the pickle. It just seemed like an optimal solution to me.

Comment: Is your table really called DB? (Same as the database?) Very confusing choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `cur.fetchall()` after `cur.execute()` and its variations.
https://psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html for more details.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import psycopg2
import pickle

# Connect to an existing database
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="DB", user="my_user", password="****", host="12.34.56.78")

# Open a cursor to perform database operations
cur = conn.cursor()

# Query the database and obtain data as Python objects
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM my_table[...];")
cur_out = np.asarray(cur.fetchall())

# Attempt to pickle the output
# Attempt to pickle the output
pickle_out = open("output.pickle","wb")
pickle.dump(cur_out, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
```